# Edit react props.children with regex to match and replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
lines = lines.map((line) => {
        let item = line.match(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gm)
        return line.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gm, `<Test>${item}</Test>`)
    })
```

Obviously this wouldn't work in react, but how could this be achievable?

```
let item = line.props.children.match(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gm)
            return line.props.children.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gm, <Test>{item}</Test>)
```

I've tried techniques with React.Children.map.

the goal is to get: `<div>Hello world this is <Test>**Nice**</Test> heh</div>`

Comment: Try this way. Remove `item` and change `${item}` to `$1`

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Basically you have an array with the following content: `['Hello world this is ', '**Nice**', ' heh']`, correct?

Comment: Considering that you have no problem building the array and that it is in this format, I will give an example answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want would be to render a component in a specific string, correct? A string that is between **. Assuming that is it, I will give an alternative using map and at the end I will put the link of a code editor in react native where I put the code there

First I'm going to create an object that looks like yours `lines.props.children`

```js
let lines = {
  props: {
    children: 'Hello world this is **nice** heh'
  }
}

/*Now I'm going to divide this string into texts that are involved in ** and those that are not involved*/

let newstr = lines.props.children.split(/(\*\*.*?\*\*)/)

/* result */
console.log(newstr)
```

Now I will use map to check if the text is wrapped with ** or not, if yes, it must return a component along with the text involved, if not, it will only return the text

```js
let lines = {
  props: {
    children: 'Hello world this is **nice** heh'
  }
}

let newstr = lines.props.children.split(/(\*\*.*?\*\*)/)

let returned = newstr.map(element => {
  if(element.match(/\*\*.*?\*\*/))
    return `<Test>${element.replace(/\*/g, '')}</Test>`
  else {
    return element
  }
})

console.log(returned)
```

Here I returned a string " ... " just to see how it would look, but in react native you would remiss **-> `**

Here you will see an example using react native: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-maxwell-01v7m?file=/src/App.js:2984-3430

I put everything inside the function `teste`

Comment: This is not possible in React, my custom element will output the following: ```(1) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
"$$typeof": Symbol(react.element)
​​
_owner: Object { tag: 0, key: null, index: 0, … }
​​
_self: null
​​
_source: null
​​
_store: Object { … }
​​
key: null
​​
props: Object { children: "Hello world this is **nice** heh" }
​​
ref: null
​​
type: "p"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
index.jsx:50:11
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why is it not possible? What happens? Are you having trouble collecting something specific? I will ask you to answer that and try to clarify your question. Anyway I will give you a new answer that may help you in this matter

Comment: Edited. See if it helps you